# How to set Accept header on the server side in Jersey 1.x for an incoming request

Tags: java, jersey

I would like to know if there is a way to set the "Accept" headers for an incoming request on server side.

This is possible to do in Jersey 2.x by implementing and registering a @prematching ContainerRequestFilter but I have not found a way to achieve the same in Jersey 1.x versions.

The idea is to set an "Accept" header that is understood by '@Produces' annotation on a resource method. I am trying to handle a use case where the client cannot set an "Accept" header. So he specifies the kind of response he expects as a query parameter such as "type=json". The idea is to read the supplied type query parameter preferably in a filter and update the "Accept" header before the resource method with the '@Produces' annotation is called.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Best regards,

Comment: did you looked at @Consumes?

Comment: Consumes annotation tells what kind of entity you are receiving(server side) like Json or Xml, which is set using content-type and not accept.. the Produces annotation tells what you are going to send back to the client, for which you need an accept header.. why should you put it as a query parameter? :\

Comment: Hi LMG, Sorry, you are right and I just had a blond moment. The call is to be made from an <img /> tag on the web. The image tag does not allow you to set Accept headers (It is an exceptional case). In such a scenario one would want to get back an image instead of JSON or XML so the server has to be told that the acceptable media type is "image/gif" say, rather than "application/json".

Comment: Hi LMG, I will remove my previous confusing comment so that we do not confuse please too much =). I have updated the description of the Question. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the preferred way to do this is with url extensions.

```
http://example.org/resource.xml
```

would return XML.

```
http://example.org/resource.json
```

would return JSON.

This can be implemented with a custom `PackagesResourceConfig` telling Jersey how to map extensions to media types:

```java
public class ExampleResourceConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig {

  public ExampleResourceConfig(Map<String, Object> props) {
    super(props);
  }

  public ExampleResourceConfig(String... packages) {
    super(packages);
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, MediaType> getMediaTypeMappings() {
    Map<String, MediaType> map = newHashMap();
    map.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
    map.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    return map;
  }

}
```

If you're using a `web.xml` to configure Jersey you can set the `javax.ws.rs.Application` property to your `PackagesResourceConfig` class name.

Comment: Hi condit, Thanks for the response. This is a great alternate but then I need to change the my API to use URL extensions instead (which is possible of course). I am using a programmatic configuration instead of web.xml but it is no problem to achieve the above with that.

Comment: How about: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#ok(java.lang.Object, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)?

Comment: Do you mean setting the Response with a different MediaType?

Comment: Sure - but based on a query parameter.

Comment: Actually this is what I ended up doing: I created an implementation of ContentResponseFilter in which I check the query parameter "type". If it is present I create a new Response using: `Response.fromResponse(containerResponse.getResponse()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();` This works and ensures that the output is of the correct type.