# Dynamic response format dependent of query parameter with Jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

All endpoints of my web service API allow to return the response in multiple formats like XML and Json. The response format is determined by a query parameter like in this request URI's:

```
https://example.com/rest/countries?format=xml
https://example.com/rest/countries?format=json
```

All my endpoints are rurrently implemented similar like in this example:

```
@GET
@Path("/countries")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getCountries(@QueryParam("format") String format) {

    if(format.equalsIgnoreCase("xml")) {
        Countries countries = getResponseFromSomewhere();
        String xml = toXmlWithJaxB(countries);
        return Response.ok(xml, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
    }
    else if(format.equalsIgnoreCase("json")) {
        Countries countries = getResponseFromSomewhere();
        String json = toJsonWithJackson(countries);
        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
    else {
        return Response.status(415).entity("Invalid format");
    }
}
```

Is there a more generic solution for this problem, so that I don't have to check and handle the format in each endpoint manually? 
Does Jackson or Jersey maybe already provide a solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without needing to implement anything custom, Jersey has the `UriConnegFilter` that checks "extensions" for the format. For example

```
https://example.com/rest/countries.xml
https://example.com/rest/countries.json
```

You need to configure the mappings

```
final Map<String, MediaType> mappings = new HashMap<>();
mappings.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
mappings.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);

return new ResourceConfig()
        .property(ServerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS, mappings);
```

Here's we're just mapping the extension to the media type. Jersey will do the rest.

If you really want to stick to only using the query parameter, then what you can do is write a `@PreMatching` `ContainerRequestFilter` where you will check for the query parameter, and then set the `Accept` header accordingly.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
@Priority(3000)
public static class QueryConnegFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Map<String, String> mappings;

    static {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        map.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        mappings = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        final String format = request.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().getFirst("format");
        if (format != null) {
            final String mediaType = mappings.get(format);
            if (mediaType != null) {
                request.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, mediaType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to register it with your application. Now you can do

```
https://example.com/rest/countries?format=xml
https://example.com/rest/countries?format=json
```

Here is a complete working test with both options listed above

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

/**
 * Run it like any other JUnit test. Only two required dependencies:
 *
 * <dependency>
 *   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *   <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
 *   <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 * </dependency>
 * <dependency>
 *   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 *   <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
 *   <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 * </dependency>
 * 
 * @author Paul Samsotha.
 */
public class UriConnegTests extends JerseyTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Model {
        private String message;
        public Model() {}
        public Model(String message) { this.message = message; }
        public String getMessage() { return this.message; }
        public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }
    }


    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @GET
        @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
        public Model get() {
            return new Model("Hello World");
        }
    }

    @Provider
    @PreMatching
    @Priority(3000)
    public static class QueryConnegFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        private static final Map<String, String> mappings;

        static {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            map.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            mappings = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
        }

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
            final String format = request.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().getFirst("format");
            if (format != null) {
                final String mediaType = mappings.get(format);
                if (mediaType != null) {
                    request.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, mediaType);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        final Map<String, MediaType> mappings = new HashMap<>();
        mappings.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        mappings.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .register(TestResource.class)
                .register(QueryConnegFilter.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true))
                .property(ServerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS, mappings);
    }

    @Test
    public void returnsXmlFromExtension() {
        final String expected = "<message>Hello World</message>";
        final String data = target("test.xml")
                .request()
                .get(String.class);
        assertThat(data, containsString(expected));
    }

    @Test
    public void returnsJsonFromExtension() {
        final String expected = "{\"message\":\"Hello World\"}";
        final String data = target("test.json")
                .request()
                .get(String.class);
        assertThat(data, is(expected));
    }

    @Test
    public void returnsXmlFromQuery() {
        final String expected = "<message>Hello World</message>";
        final String data = target("test")
                .queryParam("format", "xml")
                .request()
                .get(String.class);
        assertThat(data, containsString(expected));
    }

    @Test
    public void returnsJsonFromQuery() {
        final String expected = "{\"message\":\"Hello World\"}";
        final String data = target("test")
                .queryParam("format", "json")
                .request()
                .get(String.class);
        assertThat(data, is(expected));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jersey allows transformation of objects to xml/json.

1. Annotate your countries bean with XmlRootElement
2. Pass the annotated object to the entity method and let jersey build it
3. You'll need to add jersey-json dependency to your classpath
4. The client in this case should specify what he accepts in the header you really don't need the query param any longer. i.e. accept: application/json or application/xml

   Countries countries = getResponseFromSomewhere();
   Response.ok().entity(countries).build();

Comment: The format needs to be passed as request parameter. Passing the format within the header is not an option for me.

Comment: Without using headers i think you've got it. You could further abstract the toxml/tojson methods to a utility behind a generic "toFormat" method. This would push the logic back and make the code look cleaner in the service class. Or maybe this post will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212405/how-to-set-accept-header-on-the-server-side-in-jersey-1-x-for-an-incoming-reques.